# Build the Hermite interpolation polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials

For a set of control points $\{(0,0),(2,4),(3,5),(4,3),(7,2)\}$  build the Hermite interpolation polynomial $ H(x),$  if all derivatives up to the 4th order at the center point are additionally known:
$H'(3) = 1, H''(3) = -1, H'''(3) = 0, H''''(3) = -2. $

My attempt:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTLOH.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add your own ideas and efforts on the question in order to address more people.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and add what have you thought to do in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try tu use the triangular diagram similar to the Newton interpolation polynomial and use divided differences.

What about $H^{v}(3)$?

Is this hint it enough?

The start of the diagram is here. The rest of computation is easy to make a mistake. :)

[image]

In the 3rd column we have 1 because this is $H'(3)$. In the 4th column we have $-1/2$ because this is $f''(3)/2!$. In the next column there will be $0$ as $H'''(3)/3!$, in the next one $h''''(3)/4!=2/24=1/12.$ The rest of the divided differences is computed by the standard way.

Comment: can be more detailed, please.

Comment: Give the value of the fifth derivative at 3. It is difficult to write it using LaTeX, I will make a scan of my handwriting.

Comment: she is not known

Comment: You have written: if all derivatives up to the 5th order at the center point are additionally known. Up to 5th order, or up to 4th order as it is given?

Comment: edited. Up to 4th order.

Comment: However, I have found a nice explanation on Wilipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation In your case, tha computation is horrible. :) But the metod itself is quite easy. See the triangular diagram at the end of the article,

Comment: Thanks! "The rest of the divided differences is computed by the standard way." Can you please write more about this.

Comment: Please, study that carefully. https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104019/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/rathish-oct31/fratnode6.html

Comment: I added my attempt to the question. You can watch, please. It is right? and what to do next.

Comment: Looks not bad. I propost to construct the Hermite polynomial now and check whether the conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please look again at Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation at the Example section.